# Meaning of put in panda's HDFStore

Tags: pandas

```
from pathlib import Path
DATA_STORE = Path('SCORES.h5')

df = pd.read_csv('summary_scores.csv')
with pd.HDFStore(DATA_STORE) as store:
    store.put('scores', df)
```

Can anyone explain to me what is the meaning of the last line,  store.put('scores', df)?

Comment: stores df into HDFStore

Comment: This is the same as `df.to_hdf(DATA_STORE, key='scores')`

Comment: does it mean to add the column "scores" from df into SCORES.h5?